# Next.js: getStaticProps and getStaticPaths with dynamic routes to generate static files

Tags: next.js

I am finding the [docs](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#getstaticpaths) a little ambiguous. Given a list franchises, I would like to render out the relevant franchise detail pages at build time to avoid hitting the CMS/API at run time, as these don't change frequently.

However, it seems that even if the relevant pages are generated at build time using `getStaticPaths`, they still require the calls in `getStaticProps` to be executed at runtime. This defeats the purpose of generating static pages.

```
import {withLayout} from '../../components/layout';
import {getFranchises} from '../api/franchises';

const Franchise = (props) => {
    console.info(props);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        </>
    );
};

export async function getStaticProps({params}) {
    let data = await getFranchises();

    let franchise = data.find(x => x.id === params.id);

    return {
        props: franchise
    }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    let data = await getFranchises();

    // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
    const paths = data.map(post => ({
        params: {id: post.id},
    }));

    // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
    return {paths, fallback: false}
}

export default withLayout(Franchise);
```

Perhaps, I am doing something wrong, but I really am looking for some docs/demo on how to generate static pages at build time using `next build` that uses data from API at **build** time and does not require any further calls to populate props at **runtime**.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Both `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` [run primarily at build time](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#when-does-getstaticprops-run), that's their purpose. You're using them correctly.

Note that in dev mode (`next dev`) they [run on every request](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#runs-on-every-request-in-development).

Comment: thanks @Nikolai I was indeed using `next dev` and confirm all works as expected when doing `next build` and `next start`

Comment: Is it possible to have the same behaviour in development mode? Just run getStaticProps once?

Comment: `getStaticProps` will also run for every request in production if fallback is true and a dynamic page was not prerendered.